# jquery upward dom traversal

Tags: jquery

onI have the following html structure:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li class="gravity-form"></li>
    <li class="gravity-form-divider"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" class="btn enquire"></a>
</div>
```

With a click on 'a.btn.enquire' I'd like the following to happen; invoke slideToggleClass on li.gravity-form followed by ToggleClass on li.gravity-form-divider. Something along the lines of:

```
$('a.btn.enquire').bind('click' , function(event){
$(this).prevUntil('ul').next(li.gravity-form').slideToggle();
return false;
)};
```

Any thgoughts how to go about this?

Many thanks

Comment: Traversing up through `$(selector).closest(otherselector)` or `$(selector).parents(otherselector)`

Comment: Can you specify the question further? I'm not sure what your problem with the traversion is. You can work with `parent()` I guess.

Comment: I cannot clearly understand what are you trying to do. Do you want to select upper element? If it is you can do with JQuery selectors. Refer this : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/hierarchy-selectors/

Comment: well check my answer, hope thats what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont exactly sure why exactly you want to do like that but i am changing the code to work as you are expecting:

```
$('a.btn.enquire').live('click' , function(event){
  $(this).parent().prev().find('li.gravity-form').slideToggle(function(){
        $(this).next('li.gravity-form-divider').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/SpU8y/2/

Start using `on` instead of `bind` since it is deprecated in jquery 1.7

Comment: Hi, thanks for the 'on' advice. Unfortunately I have some jquery controlling a custom soundcloud player which relies on jquery 1.4.2 so I have to use 1.4.2 unless there is a way of using one version for a s epcific function i.e Soundcloud and another version for the rest of the site?

Comment: no issue you can use bind or live or delegate if you are using below 1.7 version jquery. updated the code and fiddle example.